# How to use terraform template to add an Azure VM into a recovery service vault?

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm developing a terraform template to automatically enroll a new built Azure VM to Azure recovery service vault. All the resources I can found in Azurerm provider are

> azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm
>
> azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm
>
> azurerm_recovery_services_vault

Seems none of them can enroll a VM to recovery service vault. Does Terraform have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the **azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm** in Terraform, and the argument `source_vm_id` shows:

> Specifies the ID of the VM to backup

It can refer to the VM which you want to back up in the recovery service vault. Create the policy with **azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm** and the recovery service vault with **azurerm_recovery_services_vault**.

**Update**

You can back up the VM with Recovery vault with **azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm** through Terraform. The code like this:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "azurevm" {
    name    = "vm_name"
    resource_group_name = "group_name"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name    = "recovery_group_name"
    location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
    name    = "azurerecoveryvaulti1"
    location = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    sku     = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm" "test" {
  name                = "azurerecoveryvaultpolicy1"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name}"

  backup = {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }

  retention_daily = {
    count = 1
  }
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${data.azurerm_virtual_machine.azurevm.id}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.test.id}"
}
```

For the test, I create the new Recovery Vault. You can use the existing with `data azurerm_recovery_services_vault`. Create a new policy then create the back up the vm with **azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm** like above.

Answer (score 0):

The resource type `azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm` is no more supported hashicorp/azurerm provider

You can use `azurerm_backup_protected_vm` instead of `azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm`,

```
resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "vm_backup_policy" {
  count               = var.vm_backup_policy_name != "" ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.vm_backup_policy_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name

  timezone = var.vm_backup_policy_timezone

  backup {
    frequency = var.vm_backup_policy_frequency
    time      = var.vm_backup_policy_time
  }

  retention_daily {
    count = var.vm_backup_daily_policy_retention
  }

  dynamic "retention_weekly" {
    for_each = var.vm_backup_weekly != {} ? [var.vm_backup_weekly] : []
    content {
      count    = lookup(retention_weekly.value, "count")
      weekdays = lookup(retention_weekly.value, "weekdays")
    }
  }

  dynamic "retention_monthly" {
    for_each = var.vm_backup_monthly != {} ? [var.vm_backup_monthly] : []
    content {
      count    = lookup(retention_monthly.value, "count")
      weekdays = lookup(retention_monthly.value, "weekdays")
      weeks    = lookup(retention_monthly.value, "weeks")
    }
  }

  dynamic "retention_yearly" {
    for_each = var.vm_backup_yearly != {} ? [var.vm_backup_yearly] : []
    content {
      count    = lookup(retention_yearly.value, "count")
      weekdays = lookup(retention_yearly.value, "weekdays")
      weeks    = lookup(retention_yearly.value, "weeks")
      months   = lookup(retention_yearly.value, "months")
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm" {
    resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
    recovery_vault_name             = var.recovery_vault_custom_name
    source_vm_id                    = var.source_vm_id
    backup_policy_id                = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.vm_backup_policy.id
}
```